# Image of $\frac{1}{z}$ on $A$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Draw the image of the function $\frac{1}{z}$ defined on the set $A=\{z:|z|=\frac{1}{2}\}$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

I am trying to get the hang on complex functions. I thought the solution for this problem would be the following but I do not know if I am right.

$|f(z)|=|\frac{1}{z}|=\frac{1}{|z|}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}=2$

So I would draw the circumference of radius $2$.

**Question:**

Is this right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Your explanation just proves that image of every $z \in A$ has modulus 2.  It doesn't prove that every element of modulus 2 is an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is completely correct. In fact, there is no problem because the domain in which $z$ has been defined does not create any problem in introducing $\frac{1}{z}$ because there is no singularity in this domain.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=\frac1z$ is a Möbius transformation, and as such takes generalized circles to generalized circles.

By your calculation, then, $f(A)=\{z: \mid z\mid=2\}$, as a Möbius transformation is determined by its effect on three points.